# SumIf OR COunt if

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I want to count dates monthwise with person name. This is my data:

```
Mandeep 1/2/2020
Mandeep 1/2/2020
Mandeep 1/2/2020
Mandeep 1/2/2020
Mandeep 1/2/2020
Mandeep 1/2/2020
Mandeep 2/2/2020
Mandeep 2/2/2020
Mandeep 2/2/2020
Mandeep 2/2/2020
Mandeep 2/2/2020
Nikhil  1/2/2020
Nikhil  1/2/2020
Nikhil  1/2/2020
Nikhil  1/2/2020
Nikhil  1/2/2020
Nikhil  1/2/2020
Nikhil  2/2/2020
Nikhil  2/2/2020
Nikhil  2/2/2020
Nikhil  2/2/2020
Nikhil  2/2/2020
```

The result should be

```
               Jan   Feb
Mandeep         6     5
nikhil          6     5
```

I need a formula for this.

Answer (score 1):

You'll first need extra columns converting the dates to months and years. This is as simple as `=MONTH(B2)` and `=YEAR(B2)`, applied to all rows.

Then you'll need a so-called [pivot table](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900) to group the data. From the menu, choose Data → Pivot table; select the existing columns and where you want the table:

[image]

Add rows, columns and values as follows:

[image]

For month names, you can use the formula `=TEXT(B2, "MMM")` instead.